# ofstream object after an if condition not working

Tags: c++

I'm facing something strange with a C++ code I'm working on. It's about an "ofstream" object that I created in order to have the data I need in a file.

Anyways, I need to place this object, which I call output1 after an "if" condition. So, any data that passes the condition I want then in the file.

Now, if I put the usual "cout" after the condition:

```
.
.
if (Check == 0) cout << data1 << " " << data2 << endl;
.
```

I'll get results printed on the screen.

But when I put my output1,

```
if (Check == 0) output1 << data1 << " " << data2 << endl;
```

then nothing is written in the file!

I have checked that my output1 object works fine somewhere else in the code. But not here! And the complier didn't mention any error or lack of declaration.

Any ideas?

Note: I can't put the code here, or even the relevant parts as it is a very long code and is not meant to be public, so I don't have the right to copy it.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote! By the way, I'm just a beginner at programming who's forced to work on complex codes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My crystal ball tells me you have two different objects both named `output1`.

The `if` statement definitely has no effect on the problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll check if there're two of them. Thanks!

Comment: Yes you are right, the original programme defined one with a similar name!!

Answer (score 2):

Your **if** is perfectly ok.

May be you forgot to flush und close the output stream?

Or you reopen the stream later?

Or you use multiple output1?

So more code fragments would result in more concrete answers answer

Comment: I closed the output between the last "return 0;" statement and the final "}" of the program; Is this the right place for it?

Comment: Excuse my poor English! The problem was, as you mentioned, that output1 was defined twice in the code. When I fixed this, everything worked well. Cheers